# json string-fields extraction, in Talend 5.5

Tags: java, json, talend, jsonpath

I have the below json string, i want to extract from this string all the `"id"` fields that are after `"number":(15124,13498)`.

I am trying to do it by jsonpath in java code  this way:

```
String pd = JsonPath.read(jsonString, "$.response.data.number.id");`
```

but i am getting an exception because of wrong jsonpath, what jsonpath exactly i should write for getting the `"id"` after `"number"` field?

Below the json String:

```
{
    "response": {
        "code": 200,
        "msg": "Success",
        "data": {
            "number": {
                "id": "13498",
                "name": "(Not in used) Daniel - 30138444",
                "network_id": 1,
                "network_type": "Facebook",
                "currency": "USD",
                "currency_info": {
                    "prefix": "$",
                    "postfix": "",
                    "name": "US Dollars"
                },
                "timezone": {
                    "id": 92,
                    "code": "PST",
                    "region": "America",
                    "locality": "Los_Angeles",
                    "offset": -7,
                    "facebook_code": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact exception?

Comment: Is your question solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine

```
 String pd = JsonPath.read("{\n" +
            "    \"response\": {\n" +
            "        \"code\": 200,\n" +
            "        \"msg\": \"Success\",\n" +
            "        \"data\": {\n" +
            "            \"number\": {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"13498\",\n" +
            "                \"name\": \"(Not in used) Daniel - 30138444\",\n" +
            "                \"network_id\": 1,\n" +
            "                \"network_type\": \"Facebook\",\n" +
            "                \"currency\": \"USD\",\n" +
            "                \"currency_info\": {\n" +
            "                    \"prefix\": \"$\",\n" +
            "                    \"postfix\": \"\",\n" +
            "                    \"name\": \"US Dollars\"\n" +
            "                },\n" +
            "                \"timezone\": {\n" +
            "                    \"id\": 92,\n" +
            "                    \"code\": \"PST\",\n" +
            "                    \"region\": \"America\",\n" +
            "                    \"locality\": \"Los_Angeles\",\n" +
            "                    \"offset\": -7,\n" +
            "                    \"facebook_code\": 1\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}", "$.response.data.number.id");
    System.out.println(pd);
```

Output:

```
  13498
```

Check whether you are passing correct `JSON` in `jsonString`

Comment: "Works fine for me" is not an answer.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg There is no other answer if there no real question. You got any other answer??

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg hmm nice opinion.

Answer (score -1):

I think from what you're looking for, you're going to get a List as an output. I also feel like it is more sensible to have the data field as an array rather than an object. Then you could try something like this;

```
List<String> ids = JsonPath.read(json, "$.response.data[*].number.id");
```

Comment: First of all it is not called a 'List' but rather an 'Array.' From my personal opinion it would make sense to have one for the data, but that being said it is very much dependent on how/where the input is coming from. I'm just trying to make OPs life easier considering he wants all ids and not just one.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera, read the answer before passing such comments.

Comment: can you see any `List/Array` in that `JSON` message?

Comment: OP clearly said above message can't pass since getting errors. And there isn't any `Array` or `List` there. There is no way to match your solution with this `JSON` message? can it solve this? If you try your solution with this `JSON` message you will get `ClassCastException`

Comment: What part of "I also feel like it is more sensible to have the data field as an array rather than an object" provided that you do something to make that happen, either by some simple code manipulation or manually changing the json message. Then and only then you could do what I wrote above.

Comment: BTW you're answer doesn't do what the OP asks for either.